# ASP.NET MVC: How many repositories?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, repository, nerddinner

I am in the process is designing a website in ASP.NET MVC and am perhaps a little confused as to the exact nature of a repository.

Following the NerdDinner example, my site should have one repository which serves up the entities as I need them. However, I have also heard that you should have different repositorys that deal with specific sets of related entities....?

In the case of my site, there will be a number of entities (around 15 tables) yet the majority are all related. Is it ok / advisable to have one repository that contains all the methods that I'll need for pulling / updating / deleting etc or should I split them down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I create a repository for each data object.

For example, a simple library database could contain the following repositories:

- AuthorRepository
- BookRepository
- PublisherRepository

Comment: so in this case which repository would return all the books by a specific author?

Comment: The bookrepository, since you are requesting books

Comment: I see. Maybe im thinkin about this the wrong way but it seems weird....in terms of entities (entity framework in my case) i cant help but thinkin that if I have the author then I have the books (author.books for example). So in that respect is seems weird to split them into different repositorys.

Answer (score 8):

I use a **generic** repository which is plenty for many entities.

For a more complex one, I simply **extend** this with what's needed.  The best of both worlds really.

Answer (score 8):

In domain driven design, there's a rule that repositories are per aggregate root. You can read more about it [here](http://devlicio.us/blogs/casey/archive/2009/02/16/ddd-aggregates-and-aggregate-roots.aspx).

The more I read, the more I think that NerdDinner is too often seen as a collection of good practices, while it's absolutely not (see [here](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/07/30/reviewing-nerddinner.aspx) for a discussion of, particularly, NerdDinner repository). That's why people often blame other MS examples like [Oxite](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/12/19/oxite-open-exchangable-informative-troubled-engine.aspx) (and [here](http://codebetter.com/blogs/karlseguin/archive/2008/12/15/oxite-oh-dear-lord-why.aspx):

> Developers will flock to it, praise
>   it, and blindly accept it as gospel
>   because it comes from Microsoft (it's
>   already well on its way). Sadly, any
>   developer which adopts its spirit will
>   be left with an unmaintainble,
>   untestable and unreadable mess

).

Answer (score 5):

If you use a generic repository which accepts types then I don't see any reason to use more than one.

we use an interface like this:

```
public interface IRepository
{
    void Save<ENTITY>(ENTITY entity)
        where ENTITY : Entity;

    void Delete<ENTITY>(ENTITY entity)
        where ENTITY : Entity;

    ENTITY Load<ENTITY>(int id)
        where ENTITY : Entity;

    IQueryable<ENTITY> Query<ENTITY>()
        where ENTITY : Entity;

    IList<ENTITY> GetAll<ENTITY>()
        where ENTITY : Entity;

    IQueryable<ENTITY> Query<ENTITY>(IDomainQuery<ENTITY> whereQuery)
        where ENTITY : Entity;

    ENTITY Get<ENTITY>(int id) where ENTITY : Entity;

    IList<ENTITY> GetObjectsForIds<ENTITY>(string ids) where ENTITY : Entity;

    void Flush();
}
```

then use in code like this:

```
var returnedObjects =  repository.GetAll<ObjectClass>();
var singleObject =  repository.Get<ObjectClass>(id);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think perhaps the verbiage of what is a repository might be confusing you. To me a repository is the data storage (ie; MS SQL Database) of where your data is being stored into. 
 
Following the [Repository Pattern](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/33695/0/page/5) I recommend setting up a single respository for each datastore. Most of my projects I use MS SQL so I create a Repository for that DB (I like using [Subsonic](http://www.subsonicproject.com/) for my DAL/ORM and it also implements the Repositry pattern and the ActiveRecord pattern) then I create Factories for each table. This lets me wrap up the Subsonic ActiveREcord classes and gives me abstraction.

Hope thats helpfull, perhaps...

Comment: I'm curious about the statement of creating a repository for each data store.   What if I have a many-to-many "entity" that does nothing more than just store 2 IDs (as it's primary key)?  Do I need to create a repository out of that, or can I just include some of the basic fetch/save methods in another, related repository?   

I thought repositories should focus more on the aggregate entities.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies guys - very helpful. This 'generic' route has me interested although being the beginner that I am Im not sure how I would go about setting it up. Im using the entity framework as my ORM....

Answer (score 2):

You should not create Repositories per each table. As queen3 said, you should create Repository per aggregate root. Like, if Products can have a Category, Category Repository should be a nested class of Products. Follow the domain logic relationship than domain objects.

Answer (score 1):

Queen3 is right, you can follow that Aggregate Root theory. I basically group my repository not thinking in Entities but how they group logically in the application I'm building.

For example:

```
CustomersRepository
OrdersRepository
...
```

In CustomerRepository I would put methods for GetCustomers, GetCustomer, AddCustomer, DeleteCustomer, AddCustomerContact, DeleteCustomerContact.

In OrdersRepository I would put methods for GetOrders, GetOrder, AddOrder, CancelOrder, CloneOrder, AddOrderDetail, DeleteOrderDetail and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use a repository per related group of entitites. i.e orderrepository might have:

Order, and OrderDetail.

and would have another for, say, Customer, CustomerProfile, etc.

This keeps the repository classes neat.

Davy